# How to fire an event when the user closes the window but not when navigating/refreshing/etc...?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to do some operations when the user clicks the [x] in the browser not when the page unloads because of a refresh or normal navigation between pages...

Obviously I can't rely on onclose, onbeforeunload or onunload events because they are also fired when navigating to other page or refreshing the same page and that's not the moment when those operations must be done...

How can I acomplish this?

Comment: Tie handlers to the things you don't want firing the message, such as all anchor tags clicks on your page. In the onbeforeunload event, check if a boolean from one of these handlers has been set. If not, prompt the message.

Comment: Buf if the user clicks a bookmark or something it is also fired, so I must find another way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this works in other browsers than IE (the specifications state that it has to be only checked in IE...) but this works:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0) || (window.event.clientX < -80)) { // close button 
        //things to do when the user closes the tab or window pressing the [x]
    } else if (window.event.altKey == true) { // ALT + F4
        //things to do when the user closes with ALT+F4
    } 
};
```

Well, this doesn't work if the user clicks on a bookmark, because it is also a clientY < 0...

Comment: Well this works but if the user clicks a bookmark it is also fired, so this is not a solution... :(